# cover flow effect for the list of pdf

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, coverflow

I wanted to know how can we implement the cover flow effect for the list of pdfs and on double  tap ,it should open respective pdf. I m really struck between ,please help me out

thanks in advance

Comment: atleast suggest me how can we load pdf s through cover flow effect

Comment: @sujay what is your exact problem have you implement cover flow effect and having problem in double tap or you wnat help in how to implement cover flow effect.

Comment: @Gypsa :i implemented it by loading the images ,but now i want to load the pdf files to it

Comment: I think you should do something like :- if you can show your pdf files as a image in cover flow and when you double click on that image then you can open pdf corresponding to that image.

Comment: @Gypsa :hey can u help me how can i implement double click event here

Comment: sure I have implemented that.

Comment: @Gypsa :can u please give some tutorial or code on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In openFlowView.m file search  this method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setUpInitialState];
}
Now when you find this replace this method by below or add lines of tapGestureRecognizer.

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setUpInitialState];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenTapped:)];   
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [tapRecognizer release];    

}
screenTapped is my method that gets called when I tap twice on cover flow.

- (void)screenTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
    NSLog(@"Screen tapped");
//put your points of your coverflow coordinates
    if(coverPointimage.x > 0 && coverPointimage.x <= 265 && coverPointimage.y >0 && coverPointimage.y <= 205){
        [self imageClicked];//either write code or made seperate method that should gets called when you do double tap.
    }


}
```

Hope this code will save your couple of hours.Happy Coding.

Comment: @sujay welcome dont hesitate to accept answers ,it will also let other people know that you found a solution to your problem. happy coding

Comment: how can i load a pdf into my app.??

Comment: you can open your pdf in a web view

Answer (score 1):

You should try out the Tapku Library for coverflow effect. Its really easy and customizable. You can find it [here](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary).